# ReSharper Settings for spacing in XML comments with attributes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, comments

I asked this [same question](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/311384) on the R# Community Forums; haven't heard anything in a few days. Thought I'd re-post on SO.

Where is the R# 6 setting for the spacing in XML comments around the equal sign for C#? I've gone through all the code formatting options I could find in the R# settings, but none seem to be affecting the spacing issue described below whenever I use the R# code-cleanup tool.

**Before R# code formatting:**

```
/// <summary>
///  Writes trace information...
/// </summary>
/// <param name="eventCache">A <see cref="T:System.Diagnostics.TraceEventCache" /> object containing....</param>
```

**After R# code clean-up formatting:**

```
/// <summary>
///   Writes trace information...
/// </summary>
/// <param name = "eventCache">A <see cref = "T:System.Diagnostics.TraceEventCache" /> object containing....</param>
```

Notice the spacing around the equal sign between 'name' and 'eventCache'; and between 'cref' and 'T:System...'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was reported as a bug, as far back as resharper 5 in October 2009, and it's especially irritating as it happens differently for different people.

The work around currently is to create a new Code Cleanup profile and de-select "Reformat embedded XML doc comments".

Comment: Full reformat profile doesnt include 'reformat embedded XML doc comments', by default.

Comment: So I notice... However, I now made a custom profile and only added that action in it but then running the reformat had no effect...

Comment: I was afraid that would be the issue. Since I can get pretty sloppy with my XML doc comments, I'll just live with this annoyance and keep the reformat xml doc comments enabled.

Comment: It's a pain but if this is still bothering you, could you not perhaps write a Visual Studio macro that formats xmldoc specifically ?

Comment: Don't know if this is version related but @Дмитрий Докшин 's answer (below) is no workaround. It is the correct solution. Question is why the hell is that an option in R#. Why would anyone ever want that indent

Answer (score 22):

In "ReSharper → Options → Code Editing → XML Doc Comments → Formatting Style → Tag content → Indent inside element that contain text" set "No indent from parent element".

Comment: This is the correct answer - others are red herrings or old (R#6) bugs